# coderpad.io disable blinking cursor

Tags: css, cursor, codemirror

I am looking to disable the blinking cursor in coderpad.io
I think its a codeMirror editor.

I am using CSS

```
.CodeMirror-cursor, div.CodeMirror-cursor {
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
}
```

But this removes the cursor altogether. I cant find a way to make the cursor visible but stop the annoying blinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inspect the html, you can see that the blinking cursor is due to style="visibility:hidden" appearing on and off in the div with the class "Codemirror-cursors".  You can override that css by adding your own css with !important at the end.  Like so:

```
.Codemirror-cursors{
    visibility: visible !important
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to CSS.. In chrome Inspect HTML where do I see the Codemirror-Cursors div?  Also I am using StyleBot extension to add custom CSS. When I type

.Codemirror-cursors {
    visibility: visible !important
}

It seems to remove the '!important' override and I still see the cursor

Comment: Thanks.. Yes 

    .CodeMirror-cursor, div.CodeMirror-cursor{
     visibility: visible !important
    }

worked!

Comment: Good to hear :)  If you could mark my comment as the answer and vote up that would be great

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
.CodeMirror-cursor, div.CodeMirror-cursor{
 visibility: visible !important
}
```

worked!